# Recursively copying files

Tags: command-line, scp, cp

How can I copy *.txt files only from a directory and all its children directories?

Say I have a folder A containing .txt files and subfolders B C etc that contain .txt files and so on and I just want all the .txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all .txt files starting in the current folder (.) and scp them one at a time to hostname and place them in the home folder.

```
for filename in $( find . -name '*.txt' ); do scp "$filename" hostname:~/ ; done
```

Edit: It is important to note you want the quotes around the file name incase the filename has a space in it, if it does and you don't quote it then the application will treat it like multiple arguments instead of one.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In my case, I ssh from my machine to another one. I want to copy files from the other machine to mine. I know the address of the other machine, but not mine

Comment: With out going through the trouble of setting up an SSH service and network firewall rules so you can ssh to your machine remotely, you could also SCP in reverse but find will not work in that manner. You will need to get a list of the files to be transferred and run scp against them, you could recursively do this in bash from your system. i.e.: scp remotesystem:pathtofile/file /folderforfiles/newlocalfile

Answer (score 1):

Try this command :

```
 cd /Parent directory
    find . -name '*.txt' | cpio -pdm /pathtowhereyouwanttocopy
```

This code will just copy .txt files and save them in a directory with their parent folders .

```
cpio copies files into an archive. It reads a list of filenames

find searches the directory tree rooted at each given file name

-pdm for overwrite destination content
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to copy from a machine I ssh to my machine. Therefore I need to use scp and I don't know the equivalent of find (cp becomes scp but what about find?)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use `rsync` for this purpose. You can easily filter files by their extension. It also provides comprehensive detail on how the transfer is progressing.

```
rsync -vr --stats --progress --include="*/" --include "*.txt" --exclude='*' SOURCE DEST
```

You mentioned that while you are on your own machine `X`, you want to get all the files that are on machine `Y`. In this case you should do this:

```
scp username@Y:/path/to/directory/on/remote/machine /path/to/destination/on/X/local/machine
```

Now let's put it all together:

```
rsync -vr --stats --progress --include="*/" --include "*.txt" --exclude='*' username@Y:/path/to/directory/on/remote/machine /path/to/destination/on/X/local/machine
```

You can try to run a test without actually copying anything by adding `--dry-run` to your `rsync` command. This will simulate the copying process.